# How do I create multiple new records in a single controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a student profile page. There's a form on that page which allows you to create new `Note` record with for that student. Works well.

[image]

I want to add a new field above the "Note" text field labeled "Who?" which allows you to enter additional students, thereby logging notes in bulk:

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to structure my form and controller action to achieve this bulk creation of new `Note` records associated with each student listed.

I'm thinking of taking this approach:

`POST` to the same action (`/notes#create`) and detect the presence of the array field `student_ids` in the `params` and then do something like this:

```
params[:student_ids].each do |s|
  note_params[:event_attributes][:student_id] = s
  note = Note.new(note_params)
  note.save
end
```

But I'd have to modify `note_params` so that it contains the proper `student_id` reference on each iteration.

Currently, on the singular form, `note_params` looks like this:

```
=> {
           "content" => "test",
  "event_attributes" => {
           "student_id" => "2",
               "user_id" => "1",
          "is_milestone" => "0",
    "happened_at_string" => ""
  }
}
```

**Is there a better/cleaner/easier way to do this without having to loop through each id and manually modify the params?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify params that way.

```
params.fetch(:student_ids, []).each do |student_id|
  student = Student.find(student_id)
  note = student.notes.new(note_params)
  note.save
end
```

Comment: But `note_params` has a `student_id` attribute with a value equal to the student id of the page you're viewing. Wouldn't I need to manually remove that? Or would `student.notes.new` overwrite it?

Comment: Always send an array, even if there is only one recipient. And don't send the student_id with every note_params. Structure your frontend logic to match this. Far easier then sending two data and deciding in the controller which is relevant.

Comment: That makes sense. But notice in my example `note_params` has a nested object called `event_attributes` which contains `student_id`. Right now that's set to the singular `student_id` in the form data. In your example, how would that property get set to the next student in the array? Could you show me what you'd expect `note_params` to be so I can structure my form properly?

Comment: Frankly I don't understand the data schema from the info provided here.

Comment: But I would assign it before save like `note.somethimg = variable`. If I get it correctly, but I don't really get the event_attributes part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better creating some sort of join table for this functionality.

This way, you can create one note, and then "copy" it by simply duplicating the join records. The downside is that one note may be accessible to multiple people, but that's okay:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :created_notes, class_name: "Note", foreign_key: :user_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :notes
end

#app/models/note.rb
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user #-> to know who made it
   has_and_belongs_to :users
end
```

Then you can use your `notes#create` method as follows:

```
#app/controllers/notes_controller.rb
class NotesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @note  = current_user.created_notes.new
      @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
   end

   def create
      @note = current_user.created_notes.new note_params
      @note.save
   end

   private

   def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:body, :user_ids)
   end
end
```

Thus, you'll be able to use the `collection_select` (or similar) functionality to define `user_ids` for your `note`:

```
#app/views/notes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @note do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, @users, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```